# jQuery: mouseover makes image visible that has the same last 4 numbers in their id as the trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a website and got stuck with the following problem:

On the website I have small dots (images) with the ids "dot0001", "dot0002", "dot0003", etc. . I also have hidden images (visibility:hidden) with the ids "info0001", "info00002", "info0003", etc.

I am looking for a jQuery solution. What I need is a code that allows the following events:

When users move the mouse over "dot0001" the image "info0001" becomes visible and when they leave "dot0001", "info0001" becomes invisible again. Same applies to "dot0002"-"info0002" ,  "dot0003"-"info0003" etc. So only the info-images with the corresponding 4 digit number become visible.

I gave it endless tries but got nowhere and there is not even a point in pasting my code.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all elements which id starts with "dot" and show/hide related "info" on mouseover/out:

```
$("[id^=dot]").hover(
  function(){
    $("#info" + this.id.substring(3)).css({"visibility":"visible"});
  },
  function(){
    $("#info" + this.id.substring(3)).css({"visibility":"hidden"});
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EGBnR/

Comment: Can I call for your help again? The "dot****" images and the respective "info****" images are overlapping at their corners. How can I make sure that I can hover over the visible "info****" image without it disappearing again? For instance, right now when I move the mouse from image "dot0001" to image "info0001" the latter disappears. How can I make sure, in this instance, "info0001" remains visible as long as the mouse is over it?

Comment: If there is no gap between them use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/EGBnR/1/

Comment: Yep, it works. The only things I had to change were the "div"s you put before the "[id^=dot]"s in the selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (though untested):

```
$('[id^="dot"]').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        var infoId = this.id.replace('dot', 'info');
        $('#' + infoId).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
        var infoId = this.id.replace('dot', 'info');
        $('#' + infoId).hide();
    }
});
```

That uses an [`attribute-starts-with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to select all elements with an `id` beginning with "dot", then binds the event handlers to them. The event handler functions themselves simply replace the "dot" part of the `id` with "info" to form the correct new one, then show or hide the element as appropriate.

Don't forget to wrap that code in a [`DOM ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handler so that it executes once the elements actually exist, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Did not work somehow but thanks for the head-up with the DOM ready (and the link) would have missed it!

Comment: @Haley What version of jQuery are you using? If it's before 1.7 then the `.on()` function won't work (it was added in 1.7).